# C# menustrip designer

Tags: visual-studio, edit, menuitem, designer

I'm not sure when this happened but when I was trying to edit a menustrip in my program (in the VS designer), I noticed that the menu items had to be grouped or merged. Like:

```
File     Edit     Format    Insert    ...
```

Instead of being able to click each menu item and add sub-items to them in the designer, they all were grouped together so I couldn't edit the menu items separately, it's quite painful.

I couldn't find any properties related to this, so how could I ungroup the menu items in the designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it turns out the designer became weird. When I wanted to add an event to the main menustrip, nothing even happened. Restarting VS seemed to have fixed it. Still quite odd.